# Python code for writing xmf for a single HDF5 that contains time sequenced data to visualise in Paraview, Visit

Tags: python, hdf5, paraview

I have been trying to load a hdf5 file in Paraview using XMF. This is in the paradigm of visualization of big data using hdf as storage and xmf as metadata-linker to hdf-file read by paraview, visit and other big data visualization softwares.

In the hdf5 file, there are sequence of tensor data named as stress_0, stress_1, ..... so on upto stress_100. Individual data set contains 64*64*64*6 data points.

Now, I would like to make a animation in Paraview in sequence using sequential tensor data stress_i for N steps. In detail, I would like to load stress_0, get a image frame from Paraview and then load stress_1 and get a image frame and so on.

General procedure to go about this is writing XMF using XDMF. But I dont understand how to go about it given the example [here](http://www.paraview.org/pipermail/paraview/2013-January/027276.html) .

Visit Community might have come across such problems before. One of their discussion [thread](http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=Using_XDMF_to_read_HDF5) explains a bit but not much.

1. Can it possible to generate this xmf using python giving hdf5 file, with all the metadata of the array it contains? I am sure it can. But dont know package for it. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: XDMF is available [here](http://www.xdmf.org/index.php/Get_Xdmf), and can be compiled into a python wrapper. However, when I used it a couple of years ago, it had some pretty major bugs that meant it didn't actually write the XMF file correctly. In the end, I used the xml.etree.ElementTree python module to write the XMF file. I'll try and clean up [this example](https://gist.github.com/ZedThree/8ee244a42717e0037010) and post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Yossarian. I have already figured it out. I will put the solution of this today. I write simple python file that does the job for me and as I am writing the hdf5 file myself I know the structure as well.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have figured it out by following couple of links I have mentioned earlier. The python file goes this way

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

# using h5py
#import h5py as h5pi

#test = h5pi.File('name_of_h5.h5',mode='r',driver='core')
#test.keys()[:] # this contains all the data files' name inside hdf5

# defining the grid
Nx,Ny,Nz =64, 64, 64

# Total time steps
tEnd = 5000

# Data dumping step
nOutput = 10

# Not taking initial points
waittime = 3400

filename = 'Name_of_h5.xmf'
f = open(filename, 'w')

# Header for xml file
f.write('''<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Xdmf SYSTEM "Xdmf.dtd" []>
<Xdmf Version="2.0">
<Domain>
<Grid Name="Box" GridType="Collection" CollectionType="Temporal">
''')

# loop over the attributes name written using time
t = 0
frameN = 0 # For time sequence 
while t <= tEnd :
    t = t + 1; 
    if( np.mod(t, nOutput) == 0 and t > waititme):

        # Naming datasets 
        dataSetName1 = 'Name_of_h5.h5:/S_%.8d'%(t)
        dataSetName2 = 'Name_of_h5.h5:/V_%.8d'%(t)

        # at individual time write the time independent Box grid. is it overdoing?
        f.write('''
        <!-- time step -->
        <Grid Name="Box %d" GridType="Uniform"> # 
        <Topology TopologyType="3DCoRectMesh" Dimensions="%d %d %d"/>
        <Geometry GeometryType="ORIGIN_DXDYDZ">
           <DataItem DataType="Float" Dimensions="3" Format="XML">0.0 0.0 0.0</DataItem>
           <DataItem DataType="Float" Dimensions="3" Format="XML">1.0 1.0 1.0</DataItem>
        </Geometry>
        <Time Value="%d" />
        '''%(frameN, Nx, Ny, Nz, frameN))

        # First Attribute
        f.write('''\n
        <Attribute Name="S" AttributeType="Scalar" Center="Node">
        <DataItem Dimensions="%d %d %d" NumberType="Float" Precision="4"
        Format="HDF">%s
        </DataItem>
        </Attribute>
        '''%(Nx, Ny, Nz, dataSetName1))

        # Second Attribute
        f.write('''\n
        <Attribute Name="N" AttributeType="Vector" Center="Node">
        <DataItem Dimensions="%d %d %d 3" NumberType="Float" Precision="4"
        Format="HDF"> %s
        </DataItem>
        </Attribute>
        </Grid>\n'''%(Nx, Ny, Nz, dataSetName2))
        frameN +=1

# End the xmf file
f.write('''
   </Grid>
</Domain>
</Xdmf>
''')
```

Comment: @yossarian : Please share your comment about the code. Another point I would like to mention is that, given a hdf5 file one can write this as well.

Comment: There is a typo in the conditional: `waititme`

Answer (score 1):

FYI, there's always [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (a project of mine), it also supports reading/writing XDMF files.

Comment: Does it handle HDF5-based XDMF?  Sorry to ask, but it’s not clear from the project page.

Comment: Yes, meshio does handle it.